# Generate an accurate DTM with photogrammetry?

Tags: qgis, dem, multi-band, canopy-height-model

I generated imagery from a low flying drone (40 M AGL) equipped with a mica sense RedEdge multi-spectral camera and have processed the imagery in PIX4D and now am attempting to do some analysis in QGIS.

I am working to create CHM for several research plots and am noticing that the minimum height in DTMs generated from imagery on the same plot differ by about up to 2 meters. This is a big difference and will drastically skew results. Some of the plant heights are below 2 meters.

Any idea on how to generate a highly accurate DTM that can be used in CHM analysis?

I do have imagery from winter months and have considered generating a DTM from the leafless season but wonder about differences in ground level due to frost heaving and changes due to erosion. Any one have experience with canopy height modelling?

Comment: Generating a DTM from the winter image seems like a good start. Do you have any reliable control points in the plot (IE, points where you wouldn't expect the height to change much, such as buildings)?

Comment: There are are some buildings within reasonable flight distance and there is also a road near by.

Comment: Did you use any ground control when collecting and processing your imagery? The accuracy of your DTM/DSM and any resulting analysis will wholly depend on this.

Comment: No I have not been able to use ground control points.